# jQuery drop down list hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have come up with.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="treatment-menu">
    <li>Always visible menu</li>
       <ul class="nav-child">
          <li>Hidden menu</li>
       </ul>
</ul>
```

**Hover function**

```
$('.treatment-menu li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.nav-child').show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('.nav-child').hide();
});
```

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/HBMfB/3/

However I can not get the `.navchild` to display when `.treatment-menu li` is hovered.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code.

Comment: you have to include it in `<li>` http://jsfiddle.net/HBMfB/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can Just use Css for that

http://jsfiddle.net/PpYQS/

```
.nav-child {

    display:none;
}
.treatment-menu:hover .nav-child
{
    display:block;
}
```

If you are using jquery you can do a [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of writing `show()` and `hide()`

http://jsfiddle.net/rbw8v/

```
$('.treatment-menu li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.nav-child').toggle();
    });
```

or [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) for slide effect.

```
$('.treatment-menu li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.nav-child').slideToggle();
    });
```

Comment: I really loved that slideToggle(). Is it possible to make it paus for some milliseconds before it toggle on mouseout?

Comment: Yes Try this `$(this).find('.nav-child').delay(500).slideToggle(100);`

Comment: This will make the sliding slower:- `$(this).find('.nav-child').delay(500).slideToggle('slow');`